# Flash live audio streaming

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, video-streaming, audio-streaming

i would like to know if there is a way to configure de live streaming audio settings in flex4.6 (as3) (because the default audio is very poor) the same way i can control the resolution of the streaming that i want to use for publishing using the codec H264:

```
    var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
    h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3);
    h264Settings.setQuality(0,80);
    h264Settings.setKeyFrameInterval(35);
    h264Settings.setMode(320, 240, 15);
    myStream.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;
```

I would like to know too if there is a way to change the codec or compression for audio, because there is a lot of info for video but i havent found a lot for LIVE audio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Finally found it searching. The solution was

```
mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic.gain = 75;
mic.rate = 44;
mic.setSilenceLevel(5, 1000);           
mic.encodeQuality =10;
```

I hope this be useful for someone.

Comment: The Speex codec in Flash has a fixed sampling rate of 16kHz.  Setting the mic.rate = 44 when using Speex has no effect. The mic.rate property is considered only when recording using the Nellymoser Asao codec. See my detailed answer on audio encoding quality in Flash at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209661/flash-as3-how-to-set-high-quality-audio-recording/32811229#32811229