# Flash AS3 - How to set high quality audio recording

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio-recording, bitrate

Currently, I'm using

```
mic.rate = 100;
```

This only gives 63kbps.

Is it possible for Flash AS3 to set bitrate higher than 63kbps?

Comment: This may have to do with the fact that you are using ffmpeg to convert it. The fact that ffmpeg is telling converting it to 63kbps may be a different thing. please post your ffmpeg params used for conversion as well as other details about **what you are actually doing in there**... else no one in here no mather how hard will try will be too faaaar away for giving you the crrect answer... cheers

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate)

> Acceptable values are 5, 8, 11, 22, and 44

So enter one of those.

And it's measured in kHz, not kbps, also according to the docs

Comment: I'ave tried that already, but still not getting value higher than 63 kbps. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @putoshop How do you know you're getting 63 kbps? Just curious. The docs say it's measured in kHz.

Comment: After recording the audio, I'm converting it to MP3(FFMPEG converter) then download the MP3 and right click on it, then in the "Details" tab, there should be Bit rate under Audio. Please scroll if not visible. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @putoshop Ahh. Regardless, it looks like 5,8,11,22 and 44 are your options for  `mic.rate`. I'm not sure how this converts/relates to kbps.

Comment: those numbers are values for kbps based on this link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html Thanks again :)

Comment: @putoshop I Ctrl+F'd "kbps" but found nothing. I searched for "kilobits" and found `encodeQuality`. Try that http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#encodeQuality

Comment: I've been into that page and found that the maximum kbps is 42.2 for the value 10. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's flash. Great quality also depends on users' hardware. You didn't post full settings for your microphone. Also value that you are using isn't valid.

Here a small snippet, for mic settings, that will give you good enough results:

```
var micOptions : MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
micOptions.echoPath = 128;
micOptions.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
micOptions.nonLinearProcessing = true;
microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
microphone.rate = 44;
microphone.enhancedOptions = micOptions;
```

Comment: @Nicholas Siver, I tried your code and still getting the same result(63kbps), perhaps it's my hardware(like you said). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The bit rate (kbps) depends on:

1. the audio codec used (**NellyMoser's Asao** or **Speex**)
2. the Asao sample rate (mic.rate) / the Speex encode quality (mic.encodeQuality) .

### NellyMoser's Asao

With Asao the sound will use from 11 to 88kbps depending on the sampling rate:

[image]

There's also a third factor with Nellymoser Asao:

> When using the Nellymoser codec, one microphone might produce more bandwidth over against another.

### Speex

With Speex the sound will use from 4 to 42kbps depending on the encoding quality (sampling rate is fixed at 16kHz with Speex):

[image]

From: http://audior.ec/blog/audio-quality-and-bitrate-in-flash-as3-web-apps/

These bitrates should reflect in the .flv where the audio is stored/recorded.